# Usage of Comparative : as ... as

Tags: comparative-constructions

Consider the following sentence : Tom is as tall as Mary. This sentence uses comparative, as ... as. Here, Tom and Mary are *evenly matched*.

In the following sentence, we used as ... as. But I want to know a grammartical structure.

> I was but five years old when my mother died, but her image is **as**
>   fresh in my mind, now that twenty years have elapsed, **as** it was at
>   the time of her death.

That is, we must find evenly matching between *her image* and *it was
at the time of her death*. How can we do this ?

Comment: The match is between his mental image now and his mental image twenty years ago.  (Presumably, his mother died twenty years ago.) Those two images are evenly matched in vividness.

Comment: Yes. It is an interpretation. Tom is to Mary what her image is to it was at the time of her death ? Her image is a noun and it was at the time of her death is a noun ?

Comment: Tom's height is to Mary's height. The freshness of the writer's mental image of his mother now is to the freshness of his mental image of his mother twenty years ago. The latter compares the quality of the two mental images (one current, one old) just as the former compares two heights (one Tom's, one Mary's).

Comment: Yes. It is a translation as I said. You are right. We can compare qualities. I mean, if I ask again, it was at the time of her death can be replaced with at the time of her death without changing meaning ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I seem to be misunderstanding your question. "**at the time of her death** can be replaced with **at the time of her death**" confuses me. Those are the same thing.

Comment: No. please read again. The clause 'it was at the time of her death' can be replaced with the phrase 'at the time of her death' without changing meaning ?

Comment: Ah, got it. The answer is yes.

Comment: The two "evenly matched" nouns are ***her image*** and ***it***, where *syntactically*, the pronoun ***it*** simply stands in for the words ***her image*** anyway. It's just that *semantically* those two terms reference different things, because the ***context*** clearly establishes that one is twenty years earlier than the other.